# Cypress element in for loop changes after first iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop, cypress

I want to have a cypress test that duplicates for different values in an array. This is simple enough but in this particular case I also have a for loop inside...

```
let extraString = [
   ['X', 'X'],
   ['Y', 'XY'],
   ['Z', 'XY']
]

let fieldLimits = [
   ['Disputed delivery', 'Additional information', 2000],
   ['Request to redeliver', 'Special instructions', 60]
]

var element = cy.get('[cy=additionalInfo]')
if (field[1] == 'Special instructions') {
   element == cy.get('[cy=specialInstructions]')
}

element.should('be.visible').and('have.text', '')

//pastes a block of text in the field
element.then($span => {
   $span.text(generatedTextString)
})

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   element
     .type(extraString[i][0])
     .should('have.text', generatedTextString + extraString[i][1])

   var remaining = 1 - i
   if (i == 2) {
     remaining = 0
   }

   cy.get('[class*=charsRemaining]')
     .should('contain.text', 'Characters remaining: ' + remaining)
}
```

The first pass of the for loop is fine where i=0 but when it comes to the second pass when i=1, the wrong element is being typed in. Instead of 'element' it actually tries to type in cy.get('[class*=charsRemaining]'). If I take out the assertion so the loop becomes...

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  element
   .type(extraString[i][0])
   .should('have.text', generatedTextString + extraString[i][1])

}
```

... then this works fine. Also if I do away with the 'element' substitute...

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   cy.get('[cy=additionalInfo]')
     .type(extraString[i][0])
     .should('have.text', generatedTextString + extraString[i][1])

   var remaining = 1 - i
   if (i == 2) {
     remaining = 0
   }

   cy.get('[class*=charsRemaining]')
     .should('contain.text', 'Characters remaining: ' + remaining)
}
```

... then this also works. Newish to JS so wondering if it's something to do with passing in the 'element' from outside the loop or the substitute of 'element' specifically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this seems to be to do with Cypress not using variable in the way I thought it would work... [Cypress: Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Return-Values)

The code now works with he following change...

```
element.then($el => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      cy.wrap($el)
        .type(extraString[i][0])
        .should('have.text', generatedTextString + extraString[i][1])

      var remaining = 1 - i
      if (i == 2) {
        remaining = 0
      }

      createQueryPage
        .charactersRemaining()
        .should('contain.text', 'Characters remaining: ' + remaining)
  }
})
```